# Decode stream data from firehose and send to HTTP endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, base64, amazon-kinesis, fluentd, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have setup a Kinesis firehose to stream MSK logs to a http endpoint. The http endpoint is a log collector (fluentd) application. The data I receive in the fluentd app is base64 encoded, I want to decode this data so that I can have additional parsing done in the log collector. For this reason I tried to include data transformation with lambda in the firehose stream.

This is the lambda code

```
import base64
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = []

    for record in event['records']:
        payload = base64.b64decode(record['data']).decode('utf-8')
        data_dict = json.loads(payload)
        
        output_record = {
            'recordId': record['recordId'],
            'result': 'Ok',
            'data': data_dict
        }
        output.append(output_record)

    print('Successfully processed {} records.'.format(len(event['records'])))
    print(output)

    return {'records': output}
```

I see the data decoded in the lambda logs however firehose logs indicate processing failed with the below error message

```
{.."errorMessage":"Check your function and make sure the output is in required format. In addition to that, make sure the processed records contain valid result status of Dropped, Ok, or ProcessingFailed",..}
```

Can firehose handle decoded data? or should I encode this back in the lambda and handle the decoding in fluentd application?

Comment: As documented, the returned record must be Base64-encoded. My guess is that what's really happening is that you're getting an "envelope" record, which holds within it a Base-64 data record (ie, data inside `data`) and you'll need to extract that inner record (and/or combine it with fields from the envelope). Print `data_dict` to verify and decide what you want to do.